# Creating radio buttons from a list in python?

Tags: python, tkinter

The code below creates a check button for each item in the list:

```
cb_strings = ['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3', 'item 4']

self.check_btns = []

for i in range(len(cb_strings)):
    v = StringVar()
    self.check_btns.append(Checkbutton(parent, width = 20, variable = v, anchor = W, onvalue = cb_strings[i], offvalue = '*', text = cb_strings[i] , command = self.display_selections))
    self.check_btns[i].var = v
    self.check_btns[i].deselect()
    self.check_btns[i].pack()
```

Could you show me how to do a similar thing, but to create radio buttons instead?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
from Tkinter import *

cb_strings = ['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3', 'item 4']

def sel():
   print "You selected the option " + str(var.get())

root = Tk()
var = StringVar()
var.set(cb_strings[0])

for item in cb_strings:
    button = Radiobutton(root, text=item, variable=var, value=item, command=sel)
    button.pack(anchor=W)

root.mainloop()
```

Also see [example from "An Introduction to Tkinter"](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/radiobutton.htm).

Comment: in your example, how would you then output the selected button?

Comment: @HayleyvanWaas sure, you need to specify a `command` function - please see the updated answer.